# Read and handle objects from chrome.storage iteratively

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-storage

I store blob objects in chrome.storage.local with increasing keys "0", "1", "2", etc. Amount of objects is not fixed. What is the best way to read and process them iteratively starting from "0"? (I can't read the next object until the previous one wasn't handled).

I know that it's possible to get all objects with this code:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
    //handle items
});
```

But in my case there can be a lot of blob files and I don't want to handle them in memory all at once.

Comment: So loop over and read them?

Comment: @epascarello It's not so simple. chrome.storage API is asynchronous and handling time can be random (I have to send these blob objects through a network in particular order). So the sequence of actions should be READ 0 -> PROCESS 0 -> READ 1 -> PROCESS 1 -> etc.

Comment: So you pull out one item, when done. You pull out the second item, and repeat until you do not find an item.

Answer (score 1):

So you just need a simple loop that when you are done, it loads the net item. Simple queue type of system.

```
(function() {

    var ind = 0;
    function getNextItem() {
        var data = chrome.storage.local.get("key" + ind, processItem);
        ind++;
    }

    function processItems(items) {

        if(!items) return;

        //do stuff here when done call next 

        getNextItem(); // call this whenever your processing is done

    }

    getNextItem();

}());
```

Comment: Looks good! I've been thinking about this approach, but I'm afraid of "call stack size exceeded" exception because of recursive calls. In my case I could have tens of thousands blob files and it can be too much http://www.2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html. Is it possible to solve this task without recursion?

Comment: I have a feeling it will not cause an exception. The only real way to handle your case is recursion for firing an event when the process is done to fire off the next step.